# auto adjust input width based on submit button width

Tags: html, css

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <button>this text can be changed</button>    
</form>
```

currently i have some code like this, the problem is the text inside the button can be changed based on the content, so i want the button and input bar can dynamically change widths based on each other. 
basically: button width based on the text length, input bar width based on the button width. and the totally width of the form is fix and should be filled with button and input bar.

also prefer a css solution than JS.
Could someone give me some help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple JavaScript 
[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/klakshman318/ac539yvb/9/)

With Css

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

```css
form {
  display: inline-flex;
}

input,
button {
  width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>increase text and see the width of input, button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if the form width is fixed, and i want the txt be on one line. (the text width will not exceed the width of the form)